# Highlight a distant link on same page

Tags: javascript, html

I am searching a solution to hightlight a distant link: On my website www.influenza-vortrag.de/vortrag.htm there is a tag cloud, which refers to text parts on the same page. When you click on single tag cloud items, the page jumps to the appropriate Link1. There is no page refresh. After clicking on a single tag cloud item Link1 should be highlighted somehow (color, background), until another tag cloud item is clicked (referring to another Link2). This should help the user to instantly find the text part where Link1 and Links2 are located. Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Show some code, please. What do the tag links look like? What do the page links look like? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

having an onClick method to change the CSS of the specific link woul be the way I would go

```
<a href="#one" onClick="myFunction(1)">link</a>
<a id="one">Link 1</a>

function myFunction(x){

code to change CSS here;
highlight the link you want, based on x and unhighlight the rest

}
```